# Node.js application throwing error on registring module

Tags: node.js, webmatrix

I am following Steven Sanderson's videos [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/07/10/node-js-development-with-webmatrix-2-express-part-2/) to get started with NodeJS. I have installed `EJS` and `ejs-middleware` modules. The server.js is like following:

```
var express=require('express'),
app = express(),
ejsMiddleware = require('ejs-middleware');

app.use(ejsMiddleware(__dirname + '/static', 'html', app));
```

But it is throwing exception on this like:

```
app.use(ejsMiddleware(__dirname + '/static', 'html', app));
```

The exception is:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'register'
    at C:\Users\...Inventify\node_modules\ejs-middleware\ejs-middleware.js:9:23
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...Inventify\server.js:8:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode-dev\release\x86\interceptor.js:211:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
```

I'm not able to get any head or tail of it. Please help me.

EDIT:- Made the following changes according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096857/13198) by @Peter Lyons:

**old**

```
registerInApp.register('.' + extension, ejs);
```

**new**

```
registerInApp.engine('.' + extension, require(ejs));
```

But now getting following exception:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'substring'
    at Function._resolveLookupPaths (module.js:235:23)
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:327:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at C:\Users\...Inventify\node_modules\ejs-middleware\ejs-middleware.js:10:47
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...Inventify\server.js:12:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `ejs-middleware` needs to be updated to call `app.engine` instead of `app.register` to work with express 3.0. As a workaround, don't pass the `app` argument to the ejsMiddleware function and instead manually register it yourself:

```
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

I updated that. It's actually straight from the [express.js documentation for app.engine](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.engine). From what I can tell (I don't use ejs personally), it looks like you don't need `ejs-middleware` at all and can just use `visionmedia/ejs` and be done with it.

Comment: I have changed this `registerInApp.register('.' + extension, ejs);` to 
        `registerInApp.engine('.' + extension, require(ejs));` but now I'm getting another error. I've updated the question.

Comment: Worked!!! Thanks. Don't know why Steven's code on github is working fine with old code :(