# NodeJS ejs templates not rendering using template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm following Steven Senderson's posts about NodeJS. I have overcome the breaking code due to version change in Express as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096085/). Now when I am accessing my `index.html` page using `localhost:13253` it is rendering contents of `index.html` as is. It is not rendering it using `layout.html`. I have traced it from `ejs.js` and `ejs-middleware` also the functions are called but layout is not being applied. The server code is as follows:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
api = require("./api/server.js"),
ejsm = require('ejs'),
ejsMiddleware = require('ejs-middleware');

app.use('/api', api);

app.use(ejsMiddleware(__dirname + '/Static', 'html', app));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Static'));

app.listen(process.env.port || 12345);
```

EDIT:-

```
//INDEX.HTML

this is homepage

//layout.html

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Inventify (alpha)</title>
        <script type="text/jscript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Styles/app.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="site-title">
            <a href="/">Iventify<span class="version">(alpha)</span></a>
        </h1>
        <div class="main-container">
            <%- body %>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('from template');
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post a sample of your index.html  and layout.html. The handling of layouts changed significantly from Express 2.x to 3.x. Now it's up to the view engine to support it rather than being baked into Express.js

Comment: @HectorCorrea I have added the code from layout and index pages

Comment: I suspect you are using Express 3.x, right? If so the problem is the support for layouts changed a lot. I wrote about this problem here http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/using-layouts-with-ejs-in-express-3-x

Comment: Yes I'm using express 3.x I will certainly look into the article.

Answer (score 0):

Run the express binary to generate the bare express project (it does this!),

```
./node_modules/express/bin/express
```

and for the part that says

```
app.set('view_engine', 'jade');
```

Change that to ejs. It will now read all files with `.ejs` as ejs templates.

Comment: Well I'll run binary. But if you see the Steve's sample at github, it is working with layout.html template file also. He is using `ejs-middleware` package.